# How to foward traffic from cloudflare to azure ingress controller?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, cloudflare

I have deployed my services and ingress controller in azure k8s cluster.
Here is the ingress address with URL:

[image]

suppose the DNS name label (optional) is "test" plus .westus.cloudapp.azure.com, so
I can access my services using test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/v1/cloud. (/v1/cloud is defined in my ingress config)

However, if I add a CNAME(test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com) in my Cloudflare and access vatest.MY_DOMAIN/v1/cloud, it returns a 404 error.

Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudflare DNS settings, create a CNAME record with the name ensure that value should be the DNS name label of your ingress controller `test.westus.cloudapp.azure.com`

[image]

After the DNS record has been set up, update the ingress controller configuration by editing the ingress controller configuration file to allow the traffic based on cluster the file location may change. Make sure that ingress controller configured in correct hostname.

To update and restart the ingress controller file once saved.

```
cloudflare_proxy:
enabled:true 
host:vatest.MY_DOMAIN
```

Once the ingress controller has been restarted, you should be able to access your services using `vatest.MY_DOMAIN/v1/cloud.`

If still error persists, there is an issue with your ingress configuration. You can check the logs of ingress controller to see if there are any errors or warnings that might help you diagnose the issue.